# UWP - how to install "local machine" independently

Tags: uwp

I think the name says it all. How to install **local machine**, **windows phone emulators**, **device** and more??? What i have just there is only: **Remote Machine** so i can not run any applications.

Added from comment (since it's very important info): Because i have windows 7 professional and also i think it is better than windows 10.. So on windows 7 i can not run local machine and others?

Comment: what operating system are you using?  I suspect you are building a UWP app on a non windows 10 computer so local machine is not an option.

Comment: Really? Because i have windows 7 professional and also i think it is better than windows 10.. So on windows 7 i can not run local machine and others? Please check it. Thank you @KenTucker

Comment: You need to debug on windows 10 to have local machine.  The windows phone emulators need windows 8 x64 pro or newer to use the hyper-v emulators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied directly from the [MSDN page with requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx) to develop for Windows 10 UWP.

> Here is the list of software that you need:
>
> - Windows 10
> - Visual Studio 2015. Make sure that the Universal Windows App Development Tools are selected from the optional features list. Without these tools, you
>   won't be able to create your universal apps.
>
> After installing this software, you need to enable your Windows 10 device for development. (You no longer need a developer license for each Windows 10 device.)

**Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 support**

> If you choose to develop Universal Windows apps with Visual Studio 2015 on a platform other than Windows 10, these are the restrictions:
>
> - **Windows 8.1**: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can use the emulators in Visual Studio, but not the simulator.
> - **Windows 7**: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can’t use the emulators or the simulator in Visual Studio either.
>
> You can only use the XAML designer if your development platform is Windows 10.

So if you want to run UWP apps locally, use an emulator or simulator (or even use the XAML designer), then you'll have to install Windows 10 (even if you think Windows 7 is better). It is just NOT possible to run an UWP app on Windows 7.